# ggplot2: Order in legend alphabetically instead of following the order of appearance in the dataset

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, legend

I am producing a ggplot2 line plot from `AESRD 2013 - SCO   Bitumen - 7y.csv` [in this folder](https://github.com/fridde/OilSandsDatabase/blob/master/downloads).  The file is automatically created on a website according to my wishes. These are several time series showing some production values, each named according to the column "Compilation". So I grouped according to "Compilation".

See this excerpt of my code in the file `plotter.r` available in the same folder (see above).

```
# "dt" is the dataframe derived from the csv file. 
# "thinned" is some vector of x-values that tells where to draw the special symbols.

p = ggplot(dt, aes(Date, Value, colour= Compilation, group = Compilation, size = plotParameter), guide=FALSE)
p = p + geom_point(data=dt[thinned,],aes(as.Date(Date), Value, colour= Compilation, shape = Compilation), size = 5)
p = p + scale_shape_manual(values = seq(0,20))
p = p + geom_line(guide = FALSE)
p = p + scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette) #cbPalette is already defined
p = p + scale_size(range=c(0.5, 2), guide=FALSE)
p = p + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
p = p + ylab("Barrels per day") + xlab("")
p = p + theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 5, vjust= -5)) 
plot(p)
```

**Here comes the nasty thing:** The legend reorders my compilations ***alphabetically***! 
[image]

I have purposely designed my csv-file so that each compilation shows up in a certain logical order (the most important series first, then following in order of some performance parameter). So the right order of the legend would simply be according to `unique(dt$Compilation)`.

My steps until now have been to introduce the column `Order` into the csv-file and experiment with that (unsuccessfully), and to change my code in all kinds of ways. With no success.

Of course, I have googled and checked most available threads on Stackoverflow. I have encountered factorization and reordering, but there is no "logical" order for my compilations except *for the order they appear in the dataset*. **Sigh**

Can anyone point me on **where** to insert **what**?

(Bonus point: How do I get rid of those horizontal lines in the symbol legend?)

Comment: apply `breaks` in both `scales`(scale_color_manual and scale_shape_manual) . If we did just one, they wouldn't match, and ggplot would split them into two legends, rather than merging them.

Comment: You solved it! If you post it as an answer (not comment), I can reward you with some reputation!

Comment: Just added the answer below  - you can go ahead vote it and approve it as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apply `breaks` in both scales(`scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`) . If we did just one, they wouldn't match, and ggplot would split them into two legends, rather than merging them

One such example is:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, shape=factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
> library(ggplot2)
> bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
> bp
```

[image]

```
bp + scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("trt1","ctrl","trt2"))
```

[image]

To reverse

```
bp + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = rev(levels(PlantGrowth$group)))
```

also try

```
bp + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = unique(levels(PlantGrowth$group)))
```

Comment: also explore `bp+ opts(legend.key = )` for legend themes

Comment: For order of appearance of items in `group`, the last line here should read: `bp + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = unique(PlantGrowth$group))`?

Answer (score 3):

To address the ordering: You probably want to fix the factor levels of `dt$Compilation` by calling sth like `dt <- transform(dt, Compilation=factor(Compilation, levels=unique(Compilation)))`before plotting.

And speaking of horizontal lines: Do you want `p = p + guides(size=FALSE)`?