# Specifying factor correctly to prevent ggplot legend from ordering alphabetically (I know this has been asked before)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I know this has been asked many times, which makes me a feel a bit better as to why I am confused.  *I am trying to keep the color order consistent with the variable selected for plotting and consistent in the legend.*

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388927/keep-ordering-of-my-data-in-ggplot-legend-where-color-and-shape-are-combined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403511/ggplot2-order-in-legend-alphabetically-instead-of-following-the-order-of-appear) for what I hoped would solve my problem, but it was either a different issue, or I must have either misunderstood or am making a mistake that I can't see.

**I specified the order of the factor variable, Group, but the colors change with the alphabetical order as opposed to the factor order**.   Since I specify the Group as a factor and specify the level order ("B" is always first as "group_1") I would have thought the color would have been consistent for "B" but it changes.

If someone could let me know what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it!

**Reproducible example**

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
Group <- c("A", "B", "C")
Value <- c(3, 3, 5)

# Create data frame
mydata   <- data.frame(Group, Value)

# Create variable for group selected for plotting
group_1 <- "B"
group_2 <- "A"

# Make a pyramid plot, making one group negative numbers for bar chart
pyramid <- mydata %>%
  filter(Group == group_1 | Group == group_2) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Group == group_2, Value * -1, Value)) %>%
    # Thought this would keep color ordering consistent
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = c(group_1, group_2)))         


pyramid_plot <- ggplot(pyramid, aes(x    = Group,
                                    y    = Value,
                                    fill = Group)
                       ) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid, Group == group_1),
           stat  = "identity"
           ) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid, Group == group_2),
           stat  = "identity"
           ) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group",
                    values = c("#1f78b4", "#33a02c"),   # blue, green
                    breaks = c(group_1, group_2),
                    labels = c(group_1, group_2)
                    )
pyramid_plot
```

[image: plot1]

```
# Now do another plot, keeping group_1 the same but changing group_2
group_1 <- "B"
group_2 <- "C"

pyramid <- mydata %>%
  filter(Group == group_1 | Group == group_2) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Group == group_2, Value * -1, Value)) %>%
  # Thought this would keep color ordering consistent
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = c(group_1, group_2)))         


pyramid_plot2 <- ggplot(pyramid, aes(x    = Group,
                                    y    = Value,
                                    fill = Group)
                       ) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid, Group == group_1),
           stat  = "identity"
           ) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pyramid, Group == group_2),
           stat  = "identity"
           ) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group",
                    values = c("#1f78b4", "#33a02c"),   # blue, green
                    breaks = c(group_1, group_2),
                    labels = c(group_1, group_2)
                    )
pyramid_plot2
```

[image: plot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Group <- c("A", "B", "C")
Value <- c(3, 3, 5)

mydata   <- data.frame(Group, Value)

group_1 <- "B"
group_2 <- "A"

pyramid <- mydata %>%
  filter(Group == group_1 | Group == group_2) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Group == group_2, Value * -1, Value)) %>%
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = c(group_1, group_2)))         


ggplot(pyramid, aes(x    = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat  = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group",
                    values = c("#1f78b4", "#33a02c"))
```

Output:

[image]

```
group_1 <- "B"
group_2 <- "C"

pyramid <- mydata %>%
  filter(Group == group_1 | Group == group_2) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Group == group_2, Value * -1, Value)) %>%
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, levels = c(group_1, group_2)))         


ggplot(pyramid, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat  = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Group",
                    values = c("#1f78b4", "#33a02c"))
```

Second output:

[image]

B is always blue.

I think the issue was with calling the `geom_bar` twice and subsetting the data. `Fill` does that for you already, so no need to further slice the data.

Comment: Yes, that must be it.  Not sure why that happens, but you are correct I don't need the subset in geom_bar.  I had changed the way I was coding this and forgot to change that part of the code.  You saved me a ton of time because I did not see that was causing the issue.  Thanks!